# Clone laptop to laptop over network

Tags: backup, clone, clonezilla

I have two laptops, both working. I need to make a clone of one in other, without removing and of the HDDs (warranty)

Is it possible using CloneZilla or any other software?

I can have both machines running Ubuntu Live USB if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done (but may only work if the laptops are very similar hardware wise, or if you have drivers for both in the OS). One way to do this would be to USB boot both laptops, run an SSH server on one and ensure it allows root access - then pipe cat (or pv - which requires an apt install pv)I over to read blocks from one and write to the other.   Once ssh  as root and pv is set up, a command like

```
pv /dev/sda | ssh x.x.x.x "cat > /dev/sda"
```

should work - but make sure understand how this works so you don't stuff something up.

Comment: This wont affect the laptop from which I'm reading, right? And even if something messes up from the second laptop (one being written to), I will still be able to install a clean OS on it, right?

Comment: For some reason, my booting options were lost (might be due to Secure Boot being ON). Just had to use the "boot-repair" GUI tool in live usb and everything came back!